# Which are the production rules for {ww | w ∈ {0, 1}*}

Tags: formal-languages

I've just started to study Formal Languages and Automata and my professor assigned me the following exercise to practice:

Determine the production rules that satisfies the Language:

```
L = {ww | w ∈ {0, 1}*}
```

And I can't figure it out...

Apparently it's a CSL. Can anyone determine these production rules?

Comment: I guess it does, but I already read it 5 times and can't actually understand it...
I am a complete noob at formal languages, it's the first exercise my professor assigned me.

Comment: Can I simply make something like this?
`S -> Z²
{Z ∈ {0, 1}∗}`
I really don't know if this is a "legal move" hahahah but it would sort it woudn't it?

Comment: Maybe you should try to understand how formal languages work, like regular languages and context-free languages, before trying to find a CSG for this language. This is a serious advice, not a mockery.

Comment: I know its not mockery and I'm looking forward to it. But I have a short time untill the exercise submit deadline and my professor just will not answear anything about it. I'll try to learn everything in one day ;-;

Comment: The rule set S->Z^2 would in principle work, but it is infinite. And generative grammars only admit finite sets of rules. Unfortunately there is no elegant and direct way. Basically, you have to generate, for example, a symbol A at the end of the first part together with a marker A' and then let the marker move to the end of the string. There you convert it to A. When you need a context-sensitive grammar, you usually have to think about how you would do it with a Turing Machine and then make this work without states.